# Prove that $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but that it has two different irreducible factors in $\mathbb{R}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Prove that $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but it has two different irreducible factors in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

I've tried to use the cyclotomic polynomial as:
$$X^5-1=(X-1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$$

So I have that my polynomial is 
$$\frac{X^5-1}{X-1}$$ and now i have to prove that is irreducible.

**The lineal change of variables are ok*(I don't know why) so I substitute $X$ by $X+1$ then I have:
$$\frac{(X+1)^5-1}{X}=\frac{X^5+5X^4+10X^3+10X^2+5X}{X}=X^4+5X^3+10X^2+10X+5$$
And now we can apply the Eisenstein criterion with p=5. So my polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$**

Now let's prove that it has two different irreducible factors in $\mathbb{R}$

I've tryed this way: $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1=(X^2+AX+B)(X^2+CX+D)$
and solve the system. But solve the system is quite difficult. Is there another way?

Comment: Try a proper substitution and then use Eisenstein.

Comment: I don't find that proper substitution, I don't know what can I should try...

Comment: Try $X\mapsto X+1$.

Comment: And the change of variable is "legal" because we "are" with isomorphisms? I never understand why we can do that, you don't change the polynomial?

Comment: Linear substitutions are ok, try to prove this as an exercise.

Comment: "Changing x to x+1" is a figure of speech: What we do is define y by x=1+y,  and calculate the polynomial as a function of y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding the complex roots of the polynomial is easy: if $\varphi=2\pi/5$, the roots are
$$
r_1=e^{i\varphi},\quad
r_2=e^{2i\varphi},\quad
r_3=e^{3i\varphi}=\bar{r}_2\quad
r_4=e^{4i\varphi}=\bar{r}_1
$$
and so the factorization over the reals is
$$
(X^2-(r_1+\bar{r}_1)X+1)((X^2-(r_2+\bar{r}_2)X+1).
$$
What you want to prove is that this factorization is not over $\mathbb{Q}$, thereby deducing that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

The procedure is standard: let $r$ be any root of the polynomial; then
$$
r^2+r+1+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}=0
$$
and so
$$
\left(r+\frac{1}{r}\right)^2+\left(r+\frac{1}{r}\right)-1=0
$$
Since the polynomial $X^2+X-1$ has no rational root, you have proved that
$$
r_1+\bar{r}_1=r_1+\frac{1}{r_1}
$$
is not rational.

---

If $p$ is prime, then $X^{p-1}+X^{p-2}+\dots+X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Write it as
$$
\frac{X^p-1}{X-1}
$$
and substitute $X=Y+1$. You'll see that Eisenstein applies.

Comment: How do yo find the complex roots so easily?

Comment: @Melanctha Because all the roots of the polynomial are fifth roots of unity (except $x=1$).

Comment: @Melanctha: one of two ways. Either you happen to know that the fifth (or nth) roots of unity, including 1, are successive powers of some value and also add up to 0, and spot that your polynomial matches that pattern. Or, given the factorisation that you already have, you observe that the roots of $\frac{X^5-1}{X-1}$ are the roots of $X^5-1$ possibly excluding the root of the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

let $$P(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x^1+1$$ 
We know if $x=\frac{a}{b}$ is root of $P(x)$ then $b|1\,$ , $\,a|1$. In the other words $a=\pm 1 $ and $b=\pm 1 $ but $P(1)=5$ and $P(-1)=1$, thus we let
$$P(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
as a result
 \begin{align}
  & bd=1 \\ 
 & ad+bc=1 \\ 
 & b+d+ac=1 \\ 
 & a+c=1 \\ 
\end{align}
This system has not solution in $Q$ because

$$d(ad+bc)=d\times\,1\to\,ad^2+c=d$$
 On the other hand $\,c=1-a$ thus 
$$ad^2+1-a=d\to\,a(d^2-1)=d-1$$ 
This implies $d=1$ or $ad+a=1$. If $d=1$ then $\left\{\begin{matrix}
   a+c=1  \\
   ac=-1  \\
\end{matrix}\right.$ that this system has not rational roots . If $\,ad+a=1\,$ then $a=\frac{1}{d+1}=\frac{b}{b+1}$ as a result
$$b+d+ac=1\to b+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{b}{b+1}\left(1-\frac{b}{b+1}\right)=1$$
we have
$$\frac{(b+1)^2}{b}+\frac{b}{(b+1)^2}=-1$$ This equation has not solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I tried this way, but how do you prove that this system has not solution in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I check it in the Matlab. I am thinking about it .

Comment: I answer your last Question. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Every polynomial splits completely over the complexes. There are only three possibitilies:

- There are four real roots
- There are two real roots and one pair of complex conjugate roots
- There are two pairs of complex conjugate roots

The roots of the polynomial are fifth roots of unity other than $1$, so there are no real roots. Thus we are in the third case, and the factorization consists of two irreducible real quadratics.

Answer (score 1):

A different route to the factorization over the reals (obviously the end result is same as in Egreg's post, but I give the factors explicitly).

Let $p(x)$ be your polynomial. By a direct calculation we see that
$$
(x^2+\frac x2+1)^2=x^4+x^3+\frac94x^2+x+1=p(x)+\frac54 x^2.
$$
This calculation is aided by palindromic symmetry of both $p(x)$ and this quadratic. Anyway, this gives us the factorization
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(x)&=(x^2+\frac x2+1)^2-(\frac{\sqrt5}2\,x)^2\\
&=(x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\, x+1)(x^2+\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\,x+1)
\end{aligned}
$$
by the usual
$$
a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)
$$
formula.

So the Golden ratio (not surprisingly given that the zeros are vertices of a regular pentagon) makes an appearance.

Comment: Right. In this case, the best proof of $\Bbb R$-reducibility is to exhibit the factorization.